# Efficiency with Type Hierarchy in Java

Tags: java, oop

I have one parent class, which is abstract class for now, for four different subclasses at level two. For one of those subclasses, I would like to make a third level of subclasses which emulate two subclasses from level two. I don't want the class that will be the parent of them to be abstract or an interface, though, and I think just making it concrete wont be very efficient.

Edit: By efficient, I mean that in the given situation, are there any alternatives to the options mentioned above?

Is there any other efficient way to represent these two classes that will essentially be the same at level two? Because the explanation was a little ambiguous, here's a picture: [image: http://i.imgur.com/mvCAS.png]

Comment: What do you mean "at the same level"? Why does it matter what "level" they're at? What's the question?

Comment: @PéterTörök Edited the question to try to make it slightly more concise. I believe you've given me the answer I need, though. Thank you.

Comment: In class diagrams, the arrow normally points to the parent, and it is an arrow, because the direction of the relation has a meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear.

> I don't want the class that will be the parent of them to be abstract or an interface, though, and I think just making it concrete wont be very efficient.

Well, if you don't want neither an abstract class, a concrete class, nor an interface, then I am afraid you are out of luck. Java offers no other choice in declaring / defining your types.

Moreover, Java does not allow multiple inheritance. That means if you want *Column Major* to be a subclass of both *ColumnMajor Table* and *Table With Deactivate Cell*, at least one of these must be an `interface`. And since in Java interfaces can only extend other interfaces, this means that *Table* must be an `interface` too.

Comment: This cleared things up. Thank you. I think it'll be best if I make RowMajor and ColumnMajor interfaces at the second level, and then implement them at the third level. Seems a little cleaner than what I was doing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're mixing the concepts of *capabilities* and *classification*. You see, inheritance is not the right tool for everything. Try to make some of those classes compositions and not subclasses. For example, having "deactivate" cells seem to be a *capability* of a table, and maybe could be a separate class that can be composed in a table class to change how a table behaves. Take a look at the *strategy* and the *state* pattern.

Comment: I will look into the strategy pattern, for sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is better to configure a class by delegation instead of derivating more subclasses. Overusing inheritance is a typical behavior of oo beginners.

In your case the approach could be to create a class configuring the distinct behavior of your actual class set.
If you design of such a class allows to be chainable you get a very flexibale, extendable architecture